# Logstash grok pattern for custom nginx access log

Tags: nginx, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a custom format of nginx `access.log` and I want to parse it with `logstash`.

The format of the access log is the following:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" ';
```

I was not able to find what kind of `grok match pattern` to use. Any idea of how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%{IPORHOST:remote_addr} - %{USER:remote_user} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] "%{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:api_path}%{URIPARAM:api_param}? %{DATA:http_version}" %{NUMBER:status:int} %{NUMBER:body_bytes_sent:int} "%{DATA:http_referer}" "%{DATA:user_agent}" "%{DATA:http_x_forwarded_for}"
```